# Is it possible to insert your own routine into the Reset procedure

Tags: reset, vector

I'm working with  ATmega328 NANO boards, and I would like to know if it is possible to INSERT my own routine, to be included in the things done during reset, BEFORE any pre-C initialization is done, or any upload of new code occurs. If this is possible, I'd like to know how. I'd want to be able to "install" this routine during setup(). I also would not expect it to work after a power loss. I'm talking about a reset caused by pressing the reset button, uploading code, opening a serial port, or any reset that was NOT caused by a loss of power.

I'm including a simple example sketch illustrating what I would LIKE to do, but it obviously won't do what I want as written, because I do not know the "magic" answer I'm seeking,

I've defined and initialized a global static byte outside of any functions. The setup() simply reads a byte from EEPROM and displays it with Serial.print(), and then stores its value in that global 'number'.  Now notice I created a void(void) function called magic(). It simply increments the global number and stores it in EEPROM. I call it "magic() because what I need to do to call it is unknown. I want some way to "install" magic() during setup(), so that it runs only as part of the reset process, before anything within code or data space is affected. By install, I don't mean just call the function. It should not actually be called unless RESET occurs.   **Whatever "magic" has to be added to make this happen, the proof of the pudding will be that after loading the sketch. every time you press RESET, or even upload the sketch again, the printed number will be different, because it was incremented and saved when reset was pushed.** NOTE: (I just edited some stupid errors here)

```
#include <EEPROM.h>

static uint8_t number =0;

void setup()
{
  uint8_t n = EEPROM.read(0);
  Serial.begin(57600); 
  Serial.print(n);
  number = n;

  // somehow, install "magic" routine here

}

void loop() { }

void magic(void)
{
 ++number;     
 EEPROM.write(0, &number);
}
```

Comment: why not at first line in setup()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. See the [documentation on memory
sections](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/mem_sections.html), from the avr-libc manual. For example:

```c++
// Run this after initializing the stack pointer and zero_reg, but
// before initializing the RAM.
void __attribute__((naked, used, section(".init3"))) magic(void)
{
    // Whatever...
}
```

Note that this runs after both a warm reset and a cold boot. See
Gerben's answer if you want to tell the difference between these two
reset conditions.

Note also that, if you just want some data to be preserved through a
reset, you can put it in the .noinit section, no need to use the EEPROM.

---

**Edit 1**: In response to the OP's comment, here is a small program
demonstrating the technique. It just quickly blinks the LED three times
early in the program initialization, then three more times, more slowly,
during `setup()`:

```c++
#include <util/delay.h>

// Blink the LED three times, fast, early in the initialization.
void __attribute__((naked, used, section(".init3"))) magic(void)
{
    DDRB |= _BV(PB5);      // pin PB5 = digital 13 as output
    for (int i= 0; i < 6; i++) {
        PINB |= _BV(PB5);  // toggle PB5
        _delay_ms(100);
    }
}

// Blink the LED three times, slowly.
void setup()
{
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(13, !(i & 1));
    }
}

void loop(){}
```

I tested it on an Uno, and it works.

Note that `magic()` runs *before* the Arduino core library has been
initialized. At this point, many core function, like `delay()`, do not
work. Any job that is done here should be done low-level, using only
direct port access and avr-libc calls.

**Edit 2**: In the previous version of this answer I forgot the `used`
attribute. It worked with the old Arduino setup I tested with, but not
with the newest IDE. Adding the `used` attribute fixes this.

Comment: Well first... I edited my "wishlist" sketch a little, because i had some stupid errors (Forgot the Serial.begin and wasn't properly formatting the EEPROM calls. But unfortunately what you've suggested compiles, but doesn't work. If you try it with the editing my corrected sketch with your suggestion, you'll see it compiles, but won't work. The proof is that "255"  is always printed. I even tried substituting a short for() loop instead of the EEPROM write: "pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
 for (int i= 0; i < 10; i++) {digitalWrite(13, i & 1); delay(20);}"  The LED doesn't flash when you press RESET.

Comment: @Randy: What I suggested does work. The Arduino core library doesn't if it has not been initialized. See my edited answer.

Comment: Hmmm... well I don't have any UNOs, only NANO boards. Doesn't work there. I do understand the wisdom of starting with a very low level and simple example. The only thing I changed in your edited code was to make the setup blink fast (300mS delay), and the magic() one 1000mS, so i wouldn't miss it. Also tried using different init levels. It compiles, but magic() has no pixie dust here so far. ;-) I'm sure this is the best advice I've gotten yet, and most likely to work. Can you think of why I'm not having any luck?

Comment: Why would "PINB |= _BV(PB5)" alternate the LED pin state?

Comment: @Randy because the datasheet says so in §18.2.2.

Comment: @Randy: My bad. I didn't notice that the current Arduino toolset now requires the `used` attribute for this to work. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Eureka! But I'm still not sure. 1st, as it turns out, adding my EEPROM.write(0, ++number); to magic()  does work. I know because if I EEprom.read(0) and print it in setup(),   it will displays 1, not 255. The problem is when RESET is pressed, I'd hope to see it print '2', but instead it remains "1". If magic() really ran BEFORE data space was initialized, that would be the case. I also tried removing the "=0", and also removed the static keyword, which should move it to the 'bss' section. But the sketch still prints always '1'. So magic() runs before setup(), but not before memory clear.

Comment: And I might add, the reason I want to save to EEPROM on RESET, is because I want to also survive a code change (or code improvement in a big project). I normally save this way on loss of power, with an electric circuit that lets me know well in advance of the AVR losing power, and since that works I can pretty easily just turn off my power switch, then turn it back on and upload my code change. But if I can also save to EEPROM on reset, that will be a major bonus in some projects.

Comment: @Randy: I tested the code in your question with no modification other than the added attributes. This time I tested with the IDE version 1.8.5. Repeatedly pressing RESET, it prints "207208209210211212..." as expected. Also, note that `magic()` runs before the memory is initialized but _after_ the bootloader, which can itself clobber some of your RAM, thus defeating your purpose. You may have to write a custom bootloader to be safe...

Comment: Well for me its printing the same value of "1" over and over again, and upgrading to 1.8.5 made no difference. I also see that if I change its initial value of 'number' to 1 instead of 0, the same code prints 129 repeatedly!. So I guess this just doesn't work with the NANO, and in any case is not reliable. And really, if magic() is going to run AFTER after "bootloader",  then the docs are lying to us.and,that pretty much brings me back to square 1. Would be nice if they actually gave us a true init0 that happened before ANYTHING when you press RESET. Guess not.

Comment: I'd like to at least experiment with "noinit" section, as I've been told elsewhere that trying to use a high level EEPROM.write() , like my example) won't work.. But now I don't think my NANO boards respect ANY rules! I made a simple sketch with byte __attribute__((naked, used, section (".noinit"))) number; Then my setup() does nothing but Serial.begin(57600); and Serial.println(number++); It compiles, but pressing reset always results in '0' being printed. If 'number' were not being initialized, and power isn't lost, I'd expect number (whatever it's value) to be +1 each run. No luck. :-(

Comment: @Randy: 1. “naked” is an attribute for code, “noinit” is for data. It doesn't make sense to mix them. 2. “noinit” means the data will not be overwritten by the startup code of the C runtime, but it doesn't prevent the bootloader from writing into that part of the RAM: the bootloader knows nothing about your sketch.

Comment: @EdgarBonet OK... that's helpful. But still..can you explain this?  Simple sketch... start with a line saying "byte number __attribute__((used, section (".noinit"))) ; Then, setup() just Serial.print()'s the number, and then increments it. Thats all. So whatever 'number' starts out as, if I press the reset button, the sketch should print one greater than that last time. That simply doesn't happen for me... the same number (usually zero) is printed over and over. I can't easily post a whole sketch in a comment, but am I doing something wrong? Or is "noinit" lying?

Comment: @Randy: Works for me on an Uno. Presumably the bootloader of the Nano uses more RAM than the Uno's optiboot. In my test, `number` was stored at 0x01c3, past the `Serial` object, its vtable, its buffers, and the core's timekeeping variables. You will have to experiment to know what addresses your bootloader overwrites.

Comment: @EdgarBone Thanks... you've confirmed what I've been suspecting, which is that the boot loader code in my nanos is not up to date. I see a lot of folks re-programming NANOs with the OPTI-BOOT, which is for the UNO, but you can use it with the NANO, and use a define to make sure all the upper analog input pins are configured. I have to either build or buy a programmer. easy to build, but they are so cheap. I'll bet the code works on my NANO with a more up to date bootloader. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the MCUSR register to see the cause of the reset. In your case you could use:

```
if( bit_is_set(MCUSR, EXTRF) )// reset button was pressed
{
    MCUSR = 0;// clear the reset-flag

    // "magic" routine here

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand this, but I don't care what caused the reset.

Comment: Are you kidding me. You specifically said reset and “NOT by loss of power”. Well; now I don’t care anymore

Comment: I think its obvious what i meant: I wanted it to WORK when a RESET occurs, but I don't expect it work if there is a loss of power.

Comment: It was **so** obvious that you have two people giving you an answer to the wrong interpretation of that part of the question!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest version (7.0, July 2018) of [Optiboot](https://github.com/Optiboot/optiboot/blob/862e9dd5e86f939cf63846372cfba3818e248f4c/optiboot/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot.c#L169), you can use the MCUSR register to check the reset cause.

You need to use the latest version because previous versions of the bootloader cleared the MCUSR before starting the sketch (as recommended in §15.9.1 of the ATmega328P datasheet). This was changed in version 7.0 ([a50f47b](https://github.com/Optiboot/optiboot/commit/a50f47b8acf28ea51e72c08914d8811563dcb869#diff-aa6fbd4fbd422af50b97d38d37fe1e1eL482)).

```
#include <EEPROM.h>

static uint8_t ch = MCUSR;

void setup() {
  MCUSR = 0;
  uint8_t n = EEPROM.read(0);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print(n);
  if ((_BV(PORF) & ch) == 0) // not a power on reset
    magic(n);
}

void loop() { }

void magic(uint8_t &number) {
   EEPROM.put(0, ++number);
}
```

Comment: Thats interesting, but I've seen this before, and I don't really care what caused the reset. what I do want, and hope I explained, is for the routine I called magic() to run when a reset occurs, before any new sketch code is loaded, or before any pre-C cleanup or initialization of memory/variables occur.

Comment: @Randy You specifically asked: "_I'm talking about a reset caused by pressing the reset button, uploading code, opening a serial port, or any reset that was NOT caused by a loss of power_." What is the reason you need it to happen before the C initializations?

Comment: I'll answer, but I don't want to side track too much into why. In a complex system, I usually put everything important into a structure (states, timers, etc.), and save it all to EEprom before turning it off. The 1st thing the code does when it starts is read the struct back out of EEprom, so it can resume in the exact same state. It would be nice if uploading a code change could first trigger my save routine too. I can find a way to do the save manually first, but it would be nice to automate it. Sadly, nothing I've tried has worked. Not even the .init sections.

Comment: @Randy That doesn't make any sense to me: when the upload is started, the MCU resets, so your configuration (states, timers) are reset and lost.

Comment: Again, the ultimate goal is to save date to EEPROM. I can assure you that saving a structure, containing all your states and timers to EEPROM, does provide a solid and reliable recovery to exactly where your program "left off", if the first thing you do is recover your structure from the EEprom where you saved to.

Comment: @Randy Yes, of course, but it doesn't matter when you read back the EEPROM config, you could do it in the setup. But if you want to save the current, unsaved state before updating, you cannot do that after a reset.

Comment: apparently not, but if there were a way to steal the RESET vector as I'd hoped, it definitely would be possible to save data to EEPROM on RESET, as long as it wasn't a power up reset.